# I have problem with HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, php-manager

I have this  error in Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 64-Bit

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.4\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Detailed Error Information:
Module     FastCgiModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    php-7.4.13
Error Code     0xc0000135
Requested URL      http://localhost:80/index.php
Physical Path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous

Works only with PHP Version 5.3.28
When I change the version in PHP manager I get this error, I also tested these versions v7.4, v7.3, v7.2. but still the same problem.
Can you help me

Comment: Migrating from PHP 5.x to 7.x is probably more than switching the runtime version.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to check is whether you have the right Visual C++ runtime package installed in your PC. If not, download and install it right away.

[Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/zh-CN/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Note: You need to install the C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 20xx that matches its version according to your PHP Version.

Comment: What version of your php and C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio? You need to install the versions that suit each other. you can try other versions.

Answer (score 0):

So for me it turned out IIS was corrupted somehow. Reinstalled IIS and everything worked out fine.
When troubleshooting I realised:
error was intermittent,
changing PHP versions had no effect
random bugs like missing libraries would occur now and again.
Log files are of no use

Very painful to debug!